# MVC, Pass model Id from view to controller

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I have a list of rows taken from a database. When I show them in my view I use foreach to show them all. At each row I have placed a submit button where I want the user to be able to select each row. For this to happen I need to pass the Id to the controller.

**Question:** How do I pass the model Id from the view to the controller?

Right now the Id in "changeCheckBoxStatusToTrue(int? id)" in the controller is returning NULL.

**My current view:**

```
foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-md-12 table" style="display: table; margin: 0 0 0 0; ">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("changeCheckBoxStatusToTrue", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        //var id = item.LearningNumberId; <-- I tried this but it didnt seem to work?
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" id="@item.LearningNumberId" type="submit" value="Vælg" />                     
                    }                        
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

**My current controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult changeCheckBoxStatusToTrue(int? id) {

        var checkboxes = db.LearningNumbers.Where(em => em.LearningNumberId == id).ToList();
        checkboxes.ForEach(em => em.setCheckBox = true);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   <input type='hidden' value="@item.LearningNumberId"/>     
   <input class="btn btn-primary" id="@item.LearningNumberId" type="submit" value="Vælg"/>
```

just add a hidden with the value and correct name (the same as the action's parameter name).

Comment: Thank you Steves. This did it!
<input type='hidden' name="id" value="@item.LearningNumberId" />
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Vælg" />

Answer (score 1):

You need a for input with the correct name to submit the value. You can use you existing submit button (just add the `name="id"` attribute to it and set the value to the id value you want), or you can add a hidden input (as [Steves suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28865386/866022)).

Additionally, you've labeled your controller code as "My current controller", but your form appears to point to the action specifically in your "Home" controller - is that the controller you intended?

Comment: Thank you Jim, I used steves but your solution worked as well. And just to answer your question - yes, it is intended to use the Home controller. :) Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create multiples forms

Replace your view code for the code below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      <div class="col-md-12 table" style="display: table; margin: 0 0 0 0; ">
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <p><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</b></p>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>
               <button type="submit" value="@item.LearningNumberId" name="id">CLick!! </button>
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   }
}
```

Note: change your input type="submit" to button 
then the name of the button will be the one who is going to bind and the value is your id

Simple as that!!!

Comment: Thank you Lucas. I tried it just to check and this works too.